# Resolution is less than in media queries, but still does not work

Tags: css, media-queries

my problem is that my media queries work but not immediately:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1520px) {
        .class {
          width: 75px;
        }

    }
```

meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In dev tools this media queries work at 1368px, between 1520-1369 doesn't. Any idea?

I checked if any other class overwrite this `.class` but doesn't. `.class` doesnt show before 1368px.

When set max-width to 1368px it doesnt work until 1231px and down...between 1368px-1231px doesnt work. It's weird.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP4w8.png)

Comment: Have you got any other media queries in your code that code be conflicting with this?

Comment: please add your all css code

Comment: I have a few hundred lines of code css

Comment: For example chrome dev tools in responsive mode have an option to visualize all media queries.

Comment: fun fact, in responsive mode this media queries work properly, but if i check on laptop it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should inspect the element in the browser to see if it is overwritten by another definition in the css file, or the the css file is not loaded. Then you can decide to add more condition to the class query or (not a good option) add the !important to the value, like 75px !important.

And to be sure to have the zoom at 100% :)

Comment: ofc i forgot about it, i declare it like you

Comment: no, i declare it before like you, just forgot in post

Comment: I tried that exactly, but in the tools there is no overriding class, and my shows only on 1368px

Comment: so you mean from 1368px down, the width: 75px doesn't appear anywhere in the developer tool?

Comment: Or does it appear, but just not being applied

Comment: from 1368px down it work, but between 1520-1369 doesnt

Comment: ah yes, does the width: 75px appear on 1520-1369? can you add something like screenshot or live url, I can help to see

Comment: when i set max-width to 1368px it work only at 1231px and down...between 1368px-1231 doesnt again, it's weird

Comment: yes, weird, can you try with this meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>

Comment: and ensure that your browser is not zoomed, try Ctrl + 0

Comment: omg i had set size to 90%...now it work. Fun fact i check it on 2 devices and both had size set to 90%.......